# Makefile: Failed to get basename to work with patsubst

Tags: c++, makefile

My Makefile:

```
compiler=g++
cflags=-g -Wall -I.
src=$(shell find . -name *.cc) #find all .cc files, with path name
srcBaseName=$(shell basename -a $(src)) # extract base names by stripping off the path
header=$(shell find . -name *.h)    # all header files
obj=$(patsubst %.cc, %.o, $(srcBaseName)) # Problematic line
bin=bin/myProgram

all:    $(bin)

$(bin): $(obj)
    $(compiler) $^ -o $@

%.o:    %.cc
    $(compiler) $(cflags) -c $^ -o $@


clean:
    rm $(obj) $(bin)
```

results in the following error:

> make: *** No rule to make target 'SomeObjectFile.o', needed by
>   'bin/myProgram'. Stop.

The problematic line:

```
obj=$(patsubst %.cc, %.o, $(srcBaseName))
```

If I change $(srcBaseName) to $(src), then everything builds fine. But in that case the .o files are going to be scattered in the corresponding folders with .cc files, which I don't want.

I'd like to have a dedicated (obj/) folder to store all the .o files.

How can I do it?

First try:

```
obj=$(patsubst %.cc, %.o, obj/$(srcBaseName))
```

Second try:

```
obj=$(patsubst %.cc, %.o, obj\/$(srcBaseName))
```

Why did they NOT work?

/**********************Edited on 16th Feb 2015**********************/

Based on the suggestions in the answers, I updated my Makefile to be this:

```
compiler=g++

# source compilation flags
cflag=-g -Wall -std=gnu++0x -I./header/
# source link flags
lflag=
# lib used by proj
lib=


tflag=-g -Wall -std=gnu++0x
# test link flags
tlflag=
# test libs
testLib=lib/libgtest.a

# source code
src=$(shell find "./src" -name "*.cc")
srcBaseName=$(shell basename -a $(src))
obj=$(addprefix obj/, $(patsubst %.cc, %.o, $(srcBaseName)))
vpath %.cc $(dir $(src))

# header files
header=$(shell find "./header" -name "*.h")

# test files
testSrc=$(shell find "./test" -name "*.cc")
testSrcBase=$(shell basename -a $(testSrc))
testObj=$(addprefix obj/, $(patsubst %.cc, %.o, $(testSrcBase)))
vpath %.cc $(dir $(testSrc))

# binary files
bin=bin/Driver
testBin=bin/Test





all: prog test


prog: $(bin)
$(bin): $(obj)
    $(compiler) $(lflag) $^ $(lib) -o $@

#$(obj): $(src) $(header)
obj/%.o: %.cc $(header)
    $(compiler) $(cflag) -c $< -o $@



test: $(testBin)

$(testBin): $(testObj)
    $(compiler) $(tlflag) $^ $(testLib) -o $@

obj/%.o: %.cc
    $(compiler) $(tflag) -c $< -o $@




clean:
    rm $(obj) $(bin) $(testObj) $(testBin)
```

Here's the intention behind the make:

make prog:

make should find all the source files(.cc) under ./src directory, and produce an .o file with the same file name in the ./obj directory, insensitive to the levels of subdirectories so that I can freely add new cc files without the need to update the Makefile. Each .o file depends on the corresponding(just the one with the same name, not all) .cc file and ALL headers(***make does not automatically know what header files a cc file includes without parsing the file; if you have a clever method to achieve this, do let me know!***). For example, ./src/subdirectory1/sample1.cc should produce ./obj/sample1.o and ./obj/sample1.o depends on ./src/subdirectory1/sample1.cc + ./header/sample1.h + ./header/sample2.h + ...

make test:

it should do similar things to the test source files in the ./test folder, with the exception that there's no header involved. In case this detail helps, I'm using Google Test.

However, my Makefile is not quite working in the intended way because it has the following problems:

1, if I run `make test`, the recipe `$(compiler) $(tflag) -c $< -o $@` is not executed(tflag means 'test compilation flag', which doesn't have the -I./header/ part; cflag means 'source code compilation flag', it has the -I./header/ part). Instead, the recipe in phony prog `$(compiler) $(cflag) -c $< -o $@` is executed. This observation comes from the output in which '-I./header/' shows up. I guess this is because the cflag pattern rule in phony prog overrides the tflag one in phony test? I vaguely remember make picks the best matching pattern rule - the two are essentially the same(I have the intention that the pattern rule under a specific phony should get executed when that phony is executed, which doesn't seem to be feasible?), so make will always pick the first one. This conclusion is verified by swapping the order of two pattern rules in the Makefile, and this time the tflag rule always gets picked. ***So a natural question to ask is, how do I execute the pattern rule under a specific phony when that phone is executed?***

2, Assuming it's not feasible to do what I wanted to do in point 1, I start to think about alternatives. Can I do something like: `#$(obj): $(src) $(header)` so that I can get rid of the pattern rule to work around the way make picks the pattern rule. However, this is obviously not correct as it's saying, each .o file in $(obj) depends on ALL src files and ALL header files. ***Is it at all a right direction?***

Thanks a lot, looking forward to hearing from you.

3 key questions have been highlighted in bold and italicized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that `make` cannot use the pattern rule

```
%.o:    %.cc
    $(compiler) $(cflags) -c $^ -o $@
```

to build `obj` since it cannot find common stems between your .o files and your .cc files to match `%`. An easy way to fix this is to tell `make` where those files are through the `vpath` directive, e.g. by adding

```
vpath %.cc $(dir $(src))
vpath %.o obj/      #not a good idea for .o files though, see below
```

and changing the pattern rule (needed by the use of `vpath %.o`) into

```
%.o:    %.cc
    $(compiler) $(cflags) -c $^ -o obj/$@
```

**EDIT**: MadScientist has made a very good point that I completely missed, based on which, a better solution that does not involve `vpath %.o` is

```
vpath %.cc $(dir $(src))
obj=$(addprefix obj/,$(patsubst %.cc, %.o, $(srcBaseName)))
obj/%.o:    %.cc
    $(compiler) $(cflags) -c $^ -o $@
```

Comment: Hi downhillFromHere: thanks for the answer. Regarding the vpath directive:
1, is vpath setting specific to each Makefile(i.e. takes the path I set on each make) or is it a global directive shared by all Makefiles in the system(i.e. Makefiles for other projects in my OS will pick it up too)?
2, I'd assume, in order for the vpath to be seen by all make commands(supposed I later decide to write other build targets for sub system in addition to the make all), I need to set the vpath with the variables like src/cflags at the beginning of the Makefile, yeah?

Comment: Hi, you're welcome. 1. I'm pretty sure it's local for a particular invocation of make, although I don't know what happens if you invoke another make in your Makefile. 2. Not exactly sure what you meant but yes, I normally set it at the beginning of the Makefile.

Comment: Just a note, you shouldn't use `vpath %.o`.  VPATH is only for finding _source_ files (files that `make` doesn't build itself but that already exist).  It won't work to use it for finding derived files (files that `make` builds).  I should say: it will work in that make can find them, but it won't work in that your makefile won't behave properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line:

`%.o:   %.cc`

That line tells make that to create some/path/file.o you will use some/path/file.cc.

If you want all .o files in one single directory, but still want to have the source files in different directories you will need one such rule for each source directory. Or, you could add all directories to the VPATH variable, something like:

`VPATH=$(dir $(src))`

Or maybe better:

`VPATH=$(dir $(SRC))`

Usuing capital letters for your variables in a Makefile is a good way to avoid confusing them with function names.

Answer (score 1):

I will do my best to also answer your new questions:

1) As you are using the gnu compilers it is possible to automatic find the dependencies of .h files in .c files. You could add rules like this to your Makefile:

```
# Where .d-files will be created for dependencies
DEP=dep

# Dependency files
DEPS = $(srcBaseName:%.cc=$(DEP)/%.d)

# Before compiling object file, also make sure dependency file is
# created to test the need for future recompilation
obj/%.o:    %.cc $(DEP)/%.d
    $(compiler) $(cflags) -c $< -o $@

# Use gnu compiler to create dependency files
$(DEPS): $(DEP)/%.d: %.cc $(filter-out $(wildcard $(DEP)), $(DEP))
    $(compiler) -MM $(cflags) -MT $@ $< > $@

# Create directories which might be needed
$(DEP) $(OBJ) $(BIN) $(MO):
    mkdir -p $@

# Let Makefile use any generated dependency files
ifneq ($(wildcard $(DEPS)),)
include $(wildcard $(DEPS))
endif
```

Please note that in the compilation rule I replaced `$^` with `$<` as we don't want to compile the dependency file.

2) I would avoid two pattern rules looking the same. Instead I would change cflag depending on the target, something like this:

```
ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),debug)
CFLAGS += -g
else
CFLAGS += -O2
endif
```

I hope these answers will guide you in the right direction

Comment: Hi Henrik. Just to share with you: I did some further search and found 'static pattern' to satisfy my requirements. It's better than regular pattern rules in my case. http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern

Comment: Yes, I should have thought of static patterns also. In my example above the rule to create dependency files use a static pattern. That might be the best solution for your tflag vs cflag.